# MySQL Select Query & use it globally(Multiple PHP pages)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm currently pulling the data from MySQL Database with the current code `Example 1`

```
function User_Details($uid){
        $uid = mysql_real_escape_string($uid);
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT uid,password,email,nickname,username,profile_pic,friend_count FROM users WHERE uid='$uid' AND status='1'");
        $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    return $data;    
}
```

I'd like to use this query across multiple PHP pages without having to write a foreach loop for every PHP file.

Currently I have it inside a class called class `Wall_Updates { }`, and I try to print it with the following code: `Example1` : < ?php echo $data['username']; ? >.

The class `Wall_Updates` is being called on the header which should also include the User_Details, so the only issue is how do I print with just the following PHP example I gave above without the need of a loop.

The class words with single fielded queries such as `Example 2` `$face = $Wall->Profile_Pic($msg_uid);` and if I echo $face it'll show my current Profile_Pic which is a single query.

`Example 3` of how I don't want to do as it's very messy.

```
<?php
if ($uid) {
    $updatesarray = $Wall->Updates($uid);
}

if ($updatesarray) {
    foreach ($updatesarray as $data) {
        $username   = $data['username'];
?>
    #HTML CODE GOES HERE
<?php }  ?>
```

`So I'd like my query to pull multiple fields from users and use it across any page without a foreach.`

PS: I'm sorry if it's not making sense, I've been complained a lot for not showing what I've tried and I hope to not get complained about it this time, I appreciate for looking at my question.

Comment: @DrewPierce just one(depending on the field and page) for each result but I need to print it in multiple different pages which are a lot, so I'd like to pull it from one query only.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done but if I echo it as the example 1 php echo $data['username']; ?> is just returns a Notice: Undefined variable: data which it is defined.

Comment: so it is not accurately saving the data ?

Comment: It's just not pulling the data period even if it is inside the class, if I print it with a foreach it will print perfectly, but because it isn't inside a foreach it will not print.

Comment: you make a query. you get back data. you seem to be having a class problem

Comment: Possible, could the issue and a fix be that I could insert a foreach inside my query and it would print..? I will try that and I will report back.

Comment: it could just be a variable scoping issue with $data in different modules. you get to module B and it has no clue what $data is. if you post the source up on pastie.org i would be happy to look at it

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.. I tried the foreach loop inside and even a while loo[ inside the query but it didn't really work.. Here is the pastie.. http://pastie.org/private/oyteyvnvmdyly8vjosrwa <-- Correct pastie. and here is how I'm trying to print it http://pastie.org/private/vjasd3tlqrguigabki7g

Comment: where is user details being called from

Comment: On the second link it's on top I forgot to add it back " $data = $Wall->User_Details($uid);"

Comment: ok where is $uid being declared. it looks empty

Comment: In the User_Details query, where it should be, correct? :/

Comment: How would I define the variable, I'm a little lost at the moment. Sorry for all the trouble and questions

Comment: Sounds good to me, added.

Comment: i need the table creation scripts

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/lum4icym8zpba4syzq196w

Comment: alright i found the problem, at least the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to issue the "or die" sql command EVERYWHERE otherwise you have no idea why it failed.

http://pastie.org/7897405

you have a column name wrong (look at the last line of the pastie

also, get off of the mysql_ stuff and get into pdo. you should know better chump !

Comment: You are perfect my man, I have learned a lot from this as well. Just perfect and will take your advice on pdo !

Comment: PS: Gosh, I've got a lot of work to do for porting from mysql_ to pdo though it looks very clean, I will do it! Thank you again!

Comment: you're welcome. i also recommend you get firephp and do debugging in firefox with the F12 key. takes about 20 min to setup. it passes debugging info back and forth with http headers

Comment: Could you explain to me how that plugin is helpful, I searched around and most people gave negative comments, is there a good true reason to use it. Especially since PHP already shows errors if there are any on php code!

Comment: it allows you to do client side debugging of what is going on server side in php, like look at variables